# What are online, paid SSH account servers for?

Tags: ssh

What are online SSH account servers  — such as FlySSH — used for? What kind of service do they provide?

Not a single one of them has anything explaining what such a service is for. There’s also nowhere that explains what an “SGDO” server is.

They all seem to explain what SSH is; which I already know as I use it with a VPS and Raspberry Pi. But what are SSH account servers — such as the one I mentioned above — for exactly?

Comment: That looks like an extremely shady website.

Comment: There are some uses for SSH servers -- e.g. I use one to connect to IRC, running `irssi` (a text IRC client) inside `screen` (a tool for leaving a program running in the background). Other people use these to run a longer download that cannot be resumed (e.g. Facebook data export) over night from a stable connection, and then use a protocol that supports resuming transfers to get the data. Most of these uses are fairly niche though.

Comment: Regarding "SGDO", I'm 90% sure they're talking about a Digital Ocean server in Singapore, but I've emailed their contact link and asked them just to be sure. Let's see if they respond.

Comment: The "sgdo server" is simply a server with that domain name: https://www.flyssh.com/create-ssh/112/ssh-server-sgdo

Comment: @Rob I think OP is asking what it _means_. The fact that the SGDO servers have SGDO in their domain name does not indicate the purpose of choosing _that_ name.

Comment: @forest, [you've already suggested that it's DigitalOcean](https://superuser.com/questions/1634872/what-are-online-paid-ssh-account-servers-for?noredirect=1#comment2498123_1634872), but not only do they [list no office there](https://www.digitalocean.com/about/) but WhoIs says it's vultr; so you'll need to ask each of them, not me.

Answer (score 13):

This is a [shell server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_account). They have many uses, usually for people who wish to run a process for a period of time without having to keep their own computer on to do so. Many shell servers place limits on the amount of CPU time or network resources that can be used, so they're often only good for simple things such as IRC bots. Some shell servers are free, but their resources are generally more limited than paid ones. I can't comment on this *particular* service. It seems quite crummy to me.

The age of shell servers is rapidly subsiding. Although they still do have some uses, VPSes have gotten so cheap that they're often superior alternatives to purchasing a shell account. Many tasks that once were only possible on shell servers are now done in a VPS.

Comment: You are technically correct. SSH servers do this by nature by simply existing. Back in the 1990s one could purchase access for the purposes you mention. This was back before virtualization and emulation. But in 2021 one can just lease a cloud server that is a virtual server and run whatever they want. So in the age of easy to access VPS boxes why would anyone need an SSH server? And in this case due to the locale of the service, the language used on past web pages and such, its seems these kind of SSH services are for VPN use; traffic routes through these servers. It is not a destination.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Lots of people run IRC clients on it, since unlike VPSes, they're easier to set up and, most importantly, many are free. Is it the statement "they have many uses" which you disagree with? Or which part of the answer is objectional to you?

Answer (score 9):

This looks dodgy as, and I would stay clear - even if my intent were questionable.

If I look at the services they are offering they all relate to hiding your source IP. This service would likely be used by those wanting to hide their location/IP address.

(There are legitimate uses for SSH servers like [bastion hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host), but these would generally be under your control, not that of a third party.  Also, jump servers could be legitimately if they had a static IP, but there is no evidence of that here - and again, why would you trust these guys not to [man-in-the-middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) your account)

Also, I don’t think SGDO is a technical acronym - I expect it us a server reference of some sort. All the services I found with that term are located in Singapore - which likely explains the “SG” part; the “DO” could be anything - maybe "Data Out" or similar?   I suspect all the sites selling this service are associated with one provider.

There is us no such thing as an SSH website, although its possible to use code embedded in a website to make an SSH / terminal connection. Also, most SSH servers can be used as SOCKS proxies - which can be used as a web proxy.

Comment: Could “SGDO” mean “[Singapore Digital Office](https://www.sgdi.gov.sg/ministries/mci/statutory-boards/imda/departments/spdr/departments/sgdo)?” If so that could mean something along the lines of internet connectivity or server hosting that is sanctioned by the Singapore government? Meaning pay a premium to get a better connection? Reading [this article](https://www.zdnet.com/article/singapore-sets-up-new-office-to-drive-national-digital-efforts/) it seems to me there is an effort to jumpstart Internet connectivity there and perhaps government established connections are being used?

Comment: As a singaporean I am doubtful this has anything to do with our government :)

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Singapore is already considered a digital leader in the region with really good connectivity.  It seems very unlikely that the Singapore government would sanction this as its a small fly-by-night company.  They dont offer anything AWS and Google Cloud dont offer - both the later have public clouds in SG and "good" reputations.

Comment: I have to -1 this because it's simply wrong in stating that such shells are generally under your control and that there is no such thing as an SSH website (there is, it's called a shell server). There are literally hundreds of shell servers out there. https://shells.red-pill.eu/ used to be a very popular list of shell servers (although it's quite outdated now). Disclaimer: I have worked for a shell provider, so I may have some bias in terms of how often they are used.

Comment: @forest A shell server is NOT a website - it has no concept of the HTTP protocol.  A user account on a *nix system (Im guessing you call that a shell server) is not the same as an SSH server - although I acknowledge ilyou can run ssh from a shell. Of-course this allows the adminstrators of the shell server to get your credentials...

Comment: @davidgo What I meant was a website for an SSH service. The service itself is not a website, but the vast majority of shell services _have_ a website, if only to tell people how to register.

Answer (score 7):

### I think in the example you provided (FlySSH) that is just a branding name.

#### Checking their history online, they seem to be VPN providers based on China and have been operating since 2011 and perhaps there is (was?) a clean way to implement a VPN via SSH tunneling that people used back then.

I have utterly no idea what that service truly provides, but as DavidGo states, the website looks quite dodgy. As in, the text seems to be machine translated “Engrish” and the links either don’t work outright — and are just HTML anchor tags — or they trigger Google ads; sign of clickbait site in action.

That said, checking [their site in the Internet Archive Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20110211045728/http://www.flyssh.com/) shows they have been around on that domain name since about February 2011. And it also shows the site back then was 100% Chinese language.

Knowing how difficult it is to circumvent the “Great Firewall of China” — since [many known methods to get around VPNs are blocked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall#Known_blocked_methods); OpenVPN, GRE, IPSec and TLS hacking — my educated guess is that this service used SSH as a way to use [SSH tunneling](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/) (aka: SSH port forwarding) to get around networking blocks.

Meaning a customer of such a service could establish an SSH tunnel for one or more ports and since SSH traffic was not monitored at the time, they could get around the national Internet block.

Does it still work? Who knows. Many legacy services still exist that technically sign up new customers, but that is not the core business they still have… Which is legacy customers.

And expanding on what [DavidGo suggests](https://superuser.com/a/1634886/167207), as far as “SGDO” goes, could “SGDO” mean “[Singapore Digital Office](https://www.sgdi.gov.sg/ministries/mci/statutory-boards/imda/departments/spdr/departments/sgdo)?” If so that could mean something along the lines of Internet connectivity — and possibly server hosting — that is sanctioned by the Singapore government? Meaning pay a premium to get a better connection? [Reading this article from June 2020](https://www.zdnet.com/article/singapore-sets-up-new-office-to-drive-national-digital-efforts/) it seems to me there is a strong effort to jumpstart Internet connectivity in Singapore and perhaps government established connections are being used and are somehow better?

Finally, if you look at the Wayback Machine timeline, it seems like the initial site was crawled in 2011 and then there is a 6-ish year gap where it came back to life in 2017.

My educated guess is that the site existed as a VPN service that catered to the Chinese VPN user market with SSH tunneling as its core service. Then it stopped existing; how it shut down is not something we can assume. Then it suddenly came back to life in 2017 because it’s a decent domain with known traffic, thus a source of some meager income from Google ad placement.

Comment: Interesting point about it possibly being useful to breach the Great Firewall if China.

Comment: SSH of itself has massive tunneling capacity. If they host the various SSH intermediate transport protocols that have been developed over the years it would be virtually impossible to filter out.

Comment: @Joshua not true. When I visited china about 15 years ago they were already blatently MITM'ung all SSH connections out the country.

Comment: @davidgo: Did you try public key auth?

Comment: So for the reader; the following obvious SSH secondary transports exist: SSH over DNS (made the news); SSH connection over SSH connection; SSH connection over SOCKS proxy over SSH connection; ssh-ssh pipeline using nc (the connection body is another SSH connection). If even one of these isn't handled, the whole thing becomes bypassed. In addition, MITMing a SSH connection that uses public key auth doesn't work as the session is rekeyed using bytes from something signed by the private key (can't be changed by the MITM guy).

Comment: @Joshua yes. In fairness, I did not try circumvent the firewall (because I did not know the risk to the people I waa staying with). You are wrong about not being able to MITM a key based session - you cant extract the private key and can detect tampering, and can probably even prevent a session remaining open but you cant stop the data being intercepted and decrypted...

Comment: See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8002/does-key-authentication-in-ssh-protect-from-mitm

Comment: SSH public key auth blocks MITM source: https://www.gremwell.com/ssh-mitm-public-key-authentication

Comment: @Joshua Very interesting.  I was skeptical but you appear to be correct.  Ta

Comment: @Joshua They can just MITM it and you'll know you're being MITMed, but you can't do anything about it. Your choices would be MITM or no internet.

Comment: @user253751: ssh lets you invoke arbitrary code on the server from the client. By Turing incompleteness theorem; a hosted shell account permits shaking off any MITM being exercised. Note that if your shell is `/bin/sh` and not `/bin/bash`, dot files aren't read in by the shell at startup so attacking the environment isn't trivial and a shell account provider designed to resist attack would stand.

Comment: @Joshua By reality laziness theorem, most people aren't going to add an extra custom encryption layer to thwart the firewall. Anyway, the firewall can be designed to block all traffic it can't analyze. And while you're probing it to figure out a workaround, strange men show up and cart you away.